# Problem with injecting of dagger subcomponent into activity

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have a hard time figuring out how to set up Dagger component hierarchy to match my vision. Any help would be greatly appreciated and please feel free to criticise the vision if you find any holes in it.

Let's get to the point.

I'm trying to redesing part of my application related to user registration. Since registration is a self contained domain I assume that it's a good candidate for a separate dagger component(RegistrationSubcomponent). Within that registration domain I will show an activity(RegistrationActivity) and on top of it few fragments(RegistrationFragment1, RegistrationFragment2, ...). I already have an application component(AppComponent) with the life scope of an application which should be a parent for RegistrationSubcomponent. AppComponent is used to inject dependecies into other activites excluding RegistrationActivity but also to a common activity(CommonActivity) which is a parent for every activity in my app including RegistrationActivity. To inject dependencies into RegistrationActivity i want to use RegistrationSubcomponent.

The RegistrationSubcomponent should be instantiated shortly before displaying RegistrationActivity and should live until after the RegistrationActivity returns. I dont't want to bind RegistrationSubcomponent lifecycle with RegistrationActivity lifecycle. Mayby in this case it may have sense but in future I will probably would like to create components for other app domains which may not neceserralily match the lifecycle of activities they encompass.

In general the problem is injection of dependecies specfied in RegistrationComponent into RegistrationActivity as well as to RegistrationFragments.

The problem is that the app crashes when navigating to RegistrationActivity with following error:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.kermit.diproblem/pl.kermit.diproblem.activities.RegistrationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class

Minimal project presenting the problem can be found at https://github.com/mariola3000/DIProblemStack01

Below I put the most important parts of code

// APP COMPONENT

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, AppAndroidBindingModule::class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(application: Application)
}

@Module(subcomponents = [RegistrationComponent::class])
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideGlobalDependency(): GlobalDependency {
        return GlobalDependency("GlobalDependency")
    }
    @Provides
    fun provideGlobal2Dependency(): Global2Dependency {
        return Global2Dependency("Global2Dependency")
    }
}

@Module
abstract class AppAndroidBindingModule {

    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector()
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

}
```

// REGISTRATION COMPONENT

```
@PerRegistration
@Subcomponent(modules = [RegistrationModule::class, RegistrationAndroidBindingModule::class])
interface RegistrationComponent {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun requestModule(module: RegistrationModule): Builder
        fun build(): RegistrationComponent
    }
}

@Module
class RegistrationModule {
    @PerRegistration
    @Provides
    fun provideRegistrationDependency(): RegistrationDependency {
        return RegistrationDependency("RegistrationDependency")
    }

    @PerRegistration
    @Provides
    fun provideRegistrationFragmentDependency(): RegistrationFragmentDependency {
        return RegistrationFragmentDependency("RegistrationFragmentDependency")
    }
}

@Module
abstract class RegistrationAndroidBindingModule {
    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindRegistrationActivity(): RegistrationActivity

    @PerFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindRegistrationFragment(): RegistrationFragment
}
```

// ACTIVITIES

```
abstract class CommonActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(){
    @Inject
    lateinit var globalDependency: GlobalDependency

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Toast.makeText(this, "global message: " + globalDependency.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

class MainActivity : CommonActivity() {
    @set:Inject
    lateinit var global2Dependency: Global2Dependency

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val text: TextView = findViewById(R.id.main_text)

        text.text = global2Dependency.message

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.main_button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, RegistrationActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}

class RegistrationActivity : CommonActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var registrationDependency: RegistrationDependency

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)

        val registrationMessage = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.registration_text)
        registrationMessage.text = registrationDependency.message

        val transaction = this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment = RegistrationFragment()
        transaction.replace(R.id.registration_fragment_container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```